# Can a javascript attribute value be determined by a manual url parameter?

Tags: javascript, xml, url, parameters, nodelist

I am trying to display data from an external .jsp file, which is set up something like this:

```
<tag>
  <innertag1 id="1">
  <innertag1 id="2">
</tag>
<tag>
  <innertag2 id="3">
  <innertag2 id="4">
</tag>
```

To display only information from only one particular "innertag" tag, I'm currently using:

```
NodeList labs = XMLInfo.getElementsByTagName("innertag1");
```

I'd like to be able to isolate any particular tag with ease. Theoretically, I could create many individual pages and simply change the values to "innertag2," "innertag3," etc., but this is obviously a bit impractical.

Is there a way to determine the value via a URL parameter? For instance, if I wanted to only display data from "innertag2," is there a way that the url *http://www.server.com/data.jsp?id=innertag2* would adjust the tagname properly?

Thank you, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing this would be pretty easy with jQuery's selector

Comment: Just as a note, real "id" values should look like identifiers (they can't start with a digit, in other words)

Comment: I don't make up the rules, I just type them into comments here :-)  That's just what the spec says.

Comment: Pointy, I got you. When writingthe example coding, I tried to make it generic and ended up accidentally doing that. Thanks

Comment: @Juan Mendes - Here's the [HTML 4.01 statement on the matter](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name): 'ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").'

Comment: That's cool, I had never heard of that!

Answer (score 2):

You can parse `document.location.href` and extract parameters from there. This is from an old HTML file where I used this technique (not sure if it's compatible on all browsers, however).

```
var args = {};

function parseArgs()
{
    var aa = document.location.href;
    if (aa.indexOf("?") != -1)
    {
        aa = aa.split("?")[1].split("&");
        for (var i=0; i<aa.length; i++)
        {
            var s = aa[i];
            var j = s.indexOf("=");
            if (j != -1)
            {
                var name = s.substr(0, j);
                var value = s.substr(j + 1);
                args[name] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've always heard it called window.location, never document.location, but it works. Also location.search saves you some work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can access parameters from the url using `location.search`.

6502's answer is almost good enough, it's not url decoding parameters. The function below is a bit more polished (descriptive variable names, no global variables)

```
function getUrlParams() {

  var paramMap = {};
  if (location.search.length == 0) {
    return paramMap;
  }
  var parts = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i ++) {
    var component = parts[i].split("=");
    paramMap [decodeURIComponent(component[0])] = decodeURIComponent(component[1]);
  }
  return paramMap;
}
```

Then you could do

```
var params = getUrlParams();
XMLInfo.getElementsByTagName(params['id']); // or params.id
```