# Get Query String with Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, query-string

Users will be hitting up against a URL that contains a query string called `inquirytype`.  For a number of reasons, I need to read in this query string with javascript (Dojo) and save its value to a variable.  I've done a fair amount of research trying to find how to do this, and I've discovered a few possibilities, but none of them seem to actually read in a query string that isn't hard-coded somewhere in the script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access parameters from the url using location.search without Dojo [Can a javascript attribute value be determined by a manual url parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822657/can-a-javascript-attribute-value-be-determined-by-a-manual-url-parameter/4822748#4822748)

```
function getUrlParams() {

  var paramMap = {};
  if (location.search.length == 0) {
    return paramMap;
  }
  var parts = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i ++) {
    var component = parts[i].split("=");
    paramMap [decodeURIComponent(component[0])] = decodeURIComponent(component[1]);
  }
  return paramMap;
}
```

Then you could do the following to extract id from the url `/hello.php?id=5&name=value`

```
var params = getUrlParams();
var id = params['id']; // or params.id
```

Dojo provides http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/queryToObject.html which is a bit smarter than my simple implementation and creates arrays out of duplicated keys.

```
var uri = "http://some.server.org/somecontext/?foo=bar&foo=bar2&bit=byte";
var query = uri.substring(uri.indexOf("?") + 1, uri.length);
var queryObject = dojo.queryToObject(query);

//The structure of queryObject will be:
// {
//   foo: ["bar", "bar2],
//   bit: "byte"
// }
```

Comment: "That is google's first result when searching for "dojo query string parameters" - ooft

Comment: you have defined the URI itself in dojo , can you please tell if Dojo has a method to call it from browser URL, or I need to do simple javascript

Comment: @friendy you can pass in `location.search`

Comment: @lawrencetierney Removed that "not so friendly" bit :-)

Answer (score 1):

In new dojo it's accessed with io-query:

```
 require([
     "dojo/io-query",
 ], function (ioQuery) {
    GET = ioQuery.queryToObject(decodeURIComponent(dojo.doc.location.search.slice(1)));
    console.log(GET.id);            
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since dojo 0.9, there is a better option, [queryToObject](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/queryToObject.html).

```
dojo.queryToObject(query)
```

See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833547/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-dojo-toolkit) with what I think is a cleaner answer.