# How do I auto-populate a text field from URL Parameter using Javascript

Tags: javascript

This page (http://forums.iis.net/t/1153336.aspx) explains how to do exactly what I am wanting to do, except due to the limitations of our system I only get to enter  javascript to pull this information into the textbox.  Can someone explain how I can use a parameter in a URL to auto fill a textbox?

Comment: Show what the parameters are likely to be, show the `input` (there's no such thing as a 'textbox' element) that it'll be populating. And, since you have a tutorial explaining how to do what you want in one language, could you explain the problems you're having translating it to JavaScript, where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear.  I am very new to programming in general, and don't know JavaScript at all, so I din't really know where to start in converting it.  The reason I was forced to use JavaScript in this situation is that I have to enter the code into a proprietary system, and the UI is limited to one input at a time and using JavaScript only.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `location.search` to access the url query and inject it into your text value

If your url is `/page.htm?x=y`, you can use the following code to set the value of a text field. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825329/get-querystring-with-dojo/7825382#7825382) tells you how to grab values from the query string

```
// See the link above for getUrlParams
var params = getUrlParams();
document.getElementById('myTextFieldId').value = params.x;
```

Notice that the example you've linked to suffers from a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting vulnerability. To avoid that, you must escape the HTML before you output it on the screen

Comment: Upvoting this answer because it's exceptionally well detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something similar using windows.location in js

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) to get parameters from the URL using JavaScript. Then set the value of your textboxes like this:

```
this.form.elements["element_name"].value = 'Some Value';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick solution, you might be interested in using this code snippet (inspiration taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/erberg-snippets/7328168#gistcomment-1564194), but modified by myself):

```
function getURLParameter(e) {
  return decodeURI((new RegExp(e + "=(.+?)(&|$)").exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1]);
}

if (getURLParameter("inputKey") === "") {
  console.log("No URL param value found.");
} else {
  document.getElementById("inputBox").value = getURLParameter("inputkey");
}
```

Let's say that your url is `example.com?inputKey=hello&nbsp;world`. If so, using the above code will fill in the input with the ID of "inputBox" with the phrase "Hello world". If the URL was just `example.com`, it wouldn't prefill the box, and instead just act as though there was nothing (show the placeholder etc).