# how to get url variable using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cfc

I would like to get URL request variables from a link and pass them to a CFC component. I already have working code (jQuery, AJAX, CFC) that will handle everything, but I just need to grab `#URL.whatever#` from a particular link.

Within Coldfusion code I can easily do so with `#URL.whatever#` but have no idea how to get it from the client side. Also, does it matter if I have been using IIS URL rewrite? I am currently rewriting `www.website.com/page.cfm?category=cat1` to `www.website.com/page/cat1`.

in both cases Coldfusion can access the request variable with `#URL.category#`, there is absolutely no difference. So how can I do this with JavaScript/jQuery, it shouldn't be complicated, right?

Comment: You'll need to write it yourself if you want this.  JavaScript has no way of knowing that the 2nd folder you have maps to category when it is a subfolder of page.

Comment: something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/7MAUv/10/

Comment: can u explain what u need in brief???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get URL parameter with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Well, we'll need more details to suggest how to get a reference to the link, but something like this should work:

HTML

```
<a id="mylink" href="www.website.com/page.cfm?category=cat1">Website.com</a>
```

JS

```
var href = document.getElementById( 'mylink' ).href;
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, what you want to use is function to parse the window.location.href variable.

```
var URL_PARAM = getUrlVars()["category"];
```

Or, if the URL to your page was www.website.com/page.cfm?category=cat1&anotherparam=12345

```
var URL_PARAM1 = getUrlVars()["category"];
var URL_PARAM2 = getUrlVars()["anotherparam"];
```

I can't say for sure how it would operate with URL rewrites.

URLVars:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts =window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[ decodeURIComponent(key)] = decodeURIComponent(value);
    });
    return vars;
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry bout that, forgot i have it in my main js file. Edited original post.

Comment: I've just tested your code, it works great, though only when URL rewrite is not set

Comment: You're using `decodeURIComponent` wrong, you have to call it on each name and value, not on the entire url string

Comment: @user1751287 Obviously this doesn't work when you're rewriting the url so that you don't have url encoded name pairs.

Answer (score 0):

This question proposes a method to get the variables, I find it slightly easier to understand than Blaise's regular expression. It also properly unencodes values from the URL  [Get Querystring with Dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825329/get-querystring-with-dojo/7825382#7825382)

```
function getUrlParams() {

  var paramMap = {};
  if (location.search.length == 0) {
    return paramMap;
  }
  var parts = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i ++) {
    var component = parts[i].split("=");
    paramMap [decodeURIComponent(component[0])] = decodeURIComponent(component[1]);
  }
  return paramMap;
}

var params = getUrlParams();
console.log(params.myParam);
```

Comment: I've just tested your code, it does the trick :) also how can I manually set category to All if (location.search.length == 0) maybe something like this var paramMap=All; is this correct

Comment: @user1751287 No, this is code for retrieving, not for setting url parameters, that would be a completely different question

Comment: to clarify when page does not contain URL parameter (www.website.com/page.cfm) I would like to set it to All. is this possible?

Comment: because if its empty it returns category=undefined

Comment: can I not retrieve it if its empty?