# jQuery Pass url parameter to a seperate functions parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, param

PHP dev needing JS help! I'm pretty new to JS and can't figure this out.

I have a small jQuery plugin **gSearch** http://gsearch.scottreeddesign.com/index.html That performs a Google Search within your page. It isnt built with POST/GET capabilities, you need to define the 'search term' within the functions parameters. I am trying to modify it.

I have 2 pages:

**search.html** contains:

```
<form action="results.html">
  <input type="text" name="q" id="term">
  <input type="button" id="search_button" onclick="this.form.submit();">
</form>
```

**results.html** contains:

```
$("#search-results").gSearch({
    search_text : 'brian griffin',
    count : 4,
    site : 'wikipedia.org',
    pagination : false  
});
```

and in the body:

```
<div id="search-results"></div>
```

Now I need to get the search term from the form and pass it as a variable to the **.gSearch** function. How would I go about this? I see posts on how to get/return url parameter but I can't seem to find any explaining how to turn it into a variable and pass it to another function? I can do this with my eyes closed with pure PHP but I'm new to JS!

Comment: Use location.search, it allows you to get the GET variables in javascript..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825329/get-querystring-with-dojo/7825382#7825382 (That shows a non-dojo solution also)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //stop default form submit
    $('#search-results').gSearch({
        search_text: $('#term').val(), //the term to search
        count: 4, //how many
        site: 'wikipedia.org', //a site to match the search against
        pagination: false //whether or not to use pagination
    }); 
});
```

We capture the form submit and stop it with preventDefault(). After, we apply gSearch to an element with the id of `search-results` (which the returned results will be appended to). We define some parameters within our object request. This should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#search_button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $search = $('#term').val();

    // Assign it to the gSearch
    $("#search-results").gSearch({
        search_text: $search,
        count: 4,
        site: 'wikipedia.org',
        pagination: false
    });


});​
```

Comment: I didn't get a chance to test others, this was the first one and it worked perfect. I do get a better understanding on how the variables work by all the posts. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to read the key/value pairs in the querystring in JavaScript.  To get a value from the querystring, [parse `location.search`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7732379/361684):

```
var searchTerms = "";
if (/\bq=([^&]+)/.test(location.search)) {
    searchTerms = decodeURIComponent(RegExp.$1);
}
$("#search-results").gSearch({
    search_text : searchTerms,
    count : 4,
    site : 'wikipedia.org',
    pagination : false  
});
```

You can't read POST values at all from JavaScript.  Those are available server-side only.